# Windows to Ubuntu desktop Remote Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

Is there an equivalent to [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) that I can use to remote into my Ubuntu desktop at home from a Windows machine?  Preferably this would be free.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [NX-server and client](http://www.nomachine.com/). They have free linux server, and the client is free as well.

3 things I like more in NX than using a normal [VNC solution](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/share-your-ubuntu-desktop-using-remote-desktop.html):

1. It's much faster
2. You can detach from a session, and
   keep it open on the server, and
   restore it later
3. The connection is encrypted.

Thinks I do not like: nxserver is not opensource.

Compromise: use [freenx server on linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) (opensource), and nxclient for windows (free as in beer).

Comment: I used today upvote limit, but +1 for motioning NX. It's my favorite solution.

Comment: +1 for NX, I use it to connect to my work machine :)

Comment: O.K. I'm back :)

Comment: can i run graphics apps on the client if I have a graphics card on the client? does NX support this?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a [VNC-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) product.

Comment: Perhaps look for vnc-server in the Ubuntu repos

Comment: Or vino which integrates with Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to launch programs from your Windows machine you will need:

Xming (Windows X Server) - http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

Putty - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

And then just SSH to your computer, but in Putty be sure to check the box "forward X11 session". After you have a terminal you should be able to launch programs like:
xlogo
kate

ect