# Windows to Ubuntu RD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows to Ubuntu desktop Remote Desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/117543/windows-to-ubuntu-desktop-remote-desktop)

Is there a way to connect to ubuntu desktop from Windows.

I'm on windows 7 trying to connect to a remote ubuntu desktop in another city.

Comment: It might help if you told us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/connect-to-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-via-windows-remote-desktop/) ma'am!

You can also use VNC and X-Forwarding to accomplish such a task.

Comment: That works despite the fact we are not on the same network?

Comment: @RachelNark As long as the proper ports are open on the intermittent routers/firewalls/etc, it should work.

Forward TCP port 3389 to the destination computer's IP address

Comment: Found the proper port number here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network

Comment: Do I need to forward on the router/modem then?

Comment: Yes.  If you are unable to access the router/modem yourself, then you may want to get in touch with someone on the other end to forward for you.

Comment: More complicated then using logmein and something of the sort.

Comment: @RachelNark Yes.  I guess I read your question wrong.  I had assumed you wanted to use Window's built-in RDC.

Comment: @RachelNark If all you need to do is get access to the machine, you can always use SSH.  This will require more port fowarding (port 21 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) is a good solution. They have both linux and windows versions.

Comment: Tried that, had issues connecting to them. They connected to me just fine. Even did service ufw stop.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! When answering questions, solely recommending software is discouraged.  If a part of your solution involves the use of a particular piece of software, I would consider using this [meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) as a guideline.